# How to calculate Energy Efficiency of electrochemical production

Tags: electrochemistry, energy, reduction-potential

I'm trying to understand some basic electrochemistry as a non chemist and struggling to find the info online effectively.

Its clear that energy efficiency = Energy(useful) / Energy (input).

So, I know how to solve for energy efficiency (η) when given a quantity of product and quantity of electricity.
η = product combustion energy / (power x time)

However, I'd like some help figuring out what to do with the information that is usually given in papers, so I can calculate η when it is not given.

Most papers report Faraday efficiency ( which I understood to be the moles of electrons that end on desired product/ invested moles of electrons)  (the denominator here can be calculated from the current and F constant).

also given are:
Catalytic surface area.
Cell voltages.
Over potentials.
ohmic drops...
etc.

For instance, I want to calculate the energy efficiency of formate production given in this paper (see image) https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-17403-1/figures/3

[image]

Alternatively:

How to calculate the bottom line here:
[image]

If you can explain how its done or points me to resources to learn this, that will be super helpful.
Thanks,
D.